# Eclipseでファイル作成時のひな形の編集

Tags: java, eclipse

EclipseでサーブレットファイルやJSPファイルを新規作成したときに自動でひな形のコードが表示されると思うのですが、そのひな形コードを自分なりにアレンジしたいです。
Eclipse内の設定で変更できますでしょうか？
それとも、ひな形のJavaファイルを見つけてきてコンパイルし直差なければいけないのでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

設定ダイアログから変更できます。
例えばJavaファイルはJava -> Code Style -> Code Templates -> Code -> New Java filesで設定できます。jspや他ファイルについても、type filter textのところでtemplateで絞り込むと設定が見つかります。

Comment: `${filecomment}`などの変数についてはhelpの[Code Templates Preferences](https://help.eclipse.org/2018-12/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fpreferences%2Fjava%2Fcodestyle%2Fref-preferences-code-templates.htm&resultof=%22filecomment%22%20%22filecom%22%20)及び[Java Editor Template variables](https://help.eclipse.org/2018-12/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fconcept-template-variables.htm)に説明があります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。解決できました。